# how to convert list of unicode url to string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I need to convert a list of unicoded urls into list of strings in python. I tried like below:

```
list_of_images = [u'http://cdn.fjfjfjfjfj.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/HA.jpg', u'http://cdn.njjk.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/HO.jpg', u'http://cdn.k.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055334RD.jpg', u'http://cdn.m.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055336RD.jpg', u'http://cdn.shf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055337RD.jpg', u'http://cdn.kjfdjhf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT1.jpg', u'http://cdn.kjdfhkjsh.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT2.jpg', u'http://cdn.kskfisjkd.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT3.jpg', u'http://cdn.djfhsjfd.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT4.jpg', u'http://cdn.jsjfhdf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT5.jpg', u'http://cdn.dfgjdhf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT6.jpg']

converted_list = [i.encode('ascii','ignore').strip() for i in list_of_images]
```

It converts each char as seperate string i ust need to remove that u. I'm new to python. Please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean `converted_list = [i.encode('ascii','ignore').strip() for i in list_of_images]` (iterate over `list_of_images` instead of `images`)?

Comment: yes, That's list_of_images. Not images. i will edit that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion to string in Python is done using the `str()` method.
You could do the following:

`converted_list = [str(image) for image in list_of_images]`

Comment: It return likes this, ['[', 'u', "'", 'h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'c', 'd', 'n', '.', 't', 'r', 'a', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'a', 'r', 't', 'n', 'e', 'r', 'w', 'e', 'b', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', '/', 'D', 'e', 's', 'i', 'y', 'a', 'I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', 's', '/', 'I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '/', '2', '/', 'n', 'x', 'd', '/', 'm', 'a', 'v', '/', 'q', 'y', 'i', '/', 'e', 'b', 'n', '/', 'H', 'A', '.', 'j', 'p', 'g', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'h'..............................

Comment: It looks like your whole list is considered as a string. Are you sure you wrote `list_of_images = [u'http://cdn...]` and not `list_of_images = "[u'http://cdn...]"` ?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry man, That list itself a unicoded one in a dict object so i took it as str(dicObj.get('list_of_images')). Now i removed that str(). It's working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
    >>> list_of_images = [u'http://cdn.fjfjfjfjfj.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/HA.jpg', u'http://cdn.njjk.com/D
esiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/HO.jpg', u'http://cdn.k.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055334RD.jpg',
 u'http://cdn.m.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055336RD.jpg', u'http://cdn.shf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/n
xd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055337RD.jpg', u'http://cdn.kjfdjhf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT1.jpg', u'http://cdn.
kjdfhkjsh.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT2.jpg', u'http://cdn.kskfisjkd.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qy
i/ebn/XT3.jpg', u'http://cdn.djfhsjfd.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT4.jpg', u'http://cdn.jsjfhdf.com/Desiy
aImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT5.jpg', u'http://cdn.dfgjdhf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT6.jpg']      
>>> newlist=[]                                                                                                         
>>> for i in range(len(list_of_images)-1):                                                                             
...  newlist.append(str(list_of_images[i]))                                                                            
...                                                                                                                    
>>> newlist                                                                                                            
['http://cdn.fjfjfjfjfj.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/HA.jpg', 'http://cdn.njjk.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd
/mav/qyi/ebn/HO.jpg', 'http://cdn.k.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055334RD.jpg', 'http://cdn.m.com/Desiy
aImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055336RD.jpg', 'http://cdn.shf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/0000055337R
D.jpg', 'http://cdn.kjfdjhf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT1.jpg', 'http://cdn.kjdfhkjsh.com/DesiyaImages/I
mage/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT2.jpg', 'http://cdn.kskfisjkd.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT3.jpg', 'http://cdn.d
jfhsjfd.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn/XT4.jpg', 'http://cdn.jsjfhdf.com/DesiyaImages/Image/2/nxd/mav/qyi/ebn
/XT5.jpg']                                                                                                             
>>>
```

Comment: it also returns like this, ['[', 'u', "'", 'h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'c', 'd', 'n', '.', 't', 'r', 'a', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'a', 'r', 't', 'n', 'e', 'r', 'w', 'e', 'b', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', '/', 'D', 'e', 's', 'i', 'y', 'a', 'I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', 's', '/', 'I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '/', '2', '/', 'n', 'x', 'd', '/', 'm', 'a', 'v', '/', 'q', 'y', 'i', '/', 'e', 'b', 'n', '/', 'H', 'A', '.', 'j', 'p', 'g', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'c', 'd'.........................

Comment: I converted that list as string before iterating it. I got solution bro. Thanks for your response. It's also working perfectly now